# CMakeList dont find CURL libraries

Tags: curl, find, cmake, package

I am trying to use CURL with a CMakeList file. But the command "**find_package(CURL)**" isnt working (it find the FindCURL.cmake file, but not the libraries).

I asked to a curl developer what curl libraries was needed, to be sure. It is the ones I already had : 
curl, libcurl3, libcurl3-gnutls and libcurl4-openssl-dev

Whats should I do to know whats is failing ?
Should I modify the auto-generated file  FindCURL.cmake, to give him the way manually ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-generated file FindCURL.cmake"? Is it a "custom" installation of curl (not something from a package manager)? Or maybe an installation on an OS without standard location for installed libraries? (for instance Windows...)